# Software centre gone after updating to 16.10

Tags: software-center, dependencies

How can I get the Software Center back? After updating from 16.04 to 16.10 it disappeared. That's what I get in my terminal when I try to get it back:

```
odin@odin-H61M-S2-B3:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
[sudo] password for odin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 software-center : Depends: python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: software-properties-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: sessioninstaller but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
odin@odin-H61M-S2-B3:~$
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` on terminal to fix missing dependencies, though I'm not bery sure if this will work.

Comment: that's what I got after running sudo apt-get install -f   Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.

Comment: You must do a `sudo apt-get update` first.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem using Synaptic Manager (as suggested by David Thefan), I found the package software-center and installed it, so Ubuntu Software is back. Thank you for your replies and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any unstable or backport repositories enabled?

Please run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and post the output?

There should be two lines that look like this:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports restricted multiverse main universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-proposed restricted multiverse main universe
```

You may or may not have a '#' in front of them. If there isn't, run command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add them, then save the file and run command:

`sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get update` and try to reinstall software center.

Comment: Please explain. I don't understand how this relates to the question.

Comment: @ David. Seems I cannot post the output as it is too long... any other way? Sorry, first time I'm posting here

Comment: @heynnema - My thinking is that if there are backports or proposed enabled, then one or some of the installed packages are too new, and prevent other software from being installed.
.

OP: If you have Synaptic installed, you can check from the Repositories menu on there whether they are enabled

Comment: Your two lines indicate **gb**.archive.ubuntu.com and would not apply if the user was in the US. Also, `Software & Updates` is the GUI way to do what you intended. I don't believe that this solves the problem.